# How would I cycle through all of the various possibilities in this situation?

Tags: c++, string, integer

I saw a programming assignment that I decided to try, and it's basically where the user inputs something like "123456789=120", and the program has to insert a '+' or '-' at different positions to make the statement true. For example, in this case, it could do 123+4-5+6-7+8-9 = 120. There are only 3^8 possible combinations, so I think it would be okay to brute force it, but I don't know exactly in what order I could go in/how to actually implement that. More specifically, I don't know what order I would go in in inserting the '+' and '-'. Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int string_to_integer(string);

int main()
{
    string input, result_string;
    int result, possibilities;

    getline(cin, input);

    //remove spaces
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        if(input[i] == ' ')
        {
            input.erase(i, 1);
        }
    }

    result_string = input.substr(input.find('=') + 1, input.length() - input.find('='));
    result = string_to_integer(result_string);
    input.erase(input.find('='), input.length() - input.find('='));

    possibilities = pow(3, input.length() - 1);
    cout << possibilities;

}

int string_to_integer(string substring)
{
    int total = 0;
    int power = 1;

    for(int i = substring.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        total += (power * (substring[i] - 48));
        power *= 10;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Count in trinary. `0=[nothing]`, `1=[minus]`, `2=[plus]`.

Comment: Recursion is useful for this kind of assignment.

Comment: Variation with repetition. You can just do it like this: go through all the 8 possible positions using a loop, then with the aid of another (inner) loop, insert a '+', a '-' or a space. Then go through the entire string, parse it an perform the computation.

Comment: Wouldn't there be 9 possible positions including the first sign?

Comment: I don't think you can add anything at the beginning.

Comment: Well you could add `+` or nothing and it wouldn't affect the number, but `-` certainly would.

Comment: I am not getting how there are `3^8` possible combinations. It should be `2^8`. There are 8 possible places to  put `+` or `-` sign and we can select at most 8 of them so `8C0 + 8C1 + ... + 8C8 = 2^8`.

Comment: You can also put nothing in each position. If we have 12=X, we can do 12, 1+2, or 1-2, i.e. 3^1. If we have 123=X, we can do 123, 1+23, 1-23, 12+3, 12-3, 1+2+3, 1+2-3, 1-2-3, or 1-2+3, i.e. 3^2.

Comment: It leaves out cases like -1+23, -1+2-3, ... as pointed out by @HunterMcMillen. So the total number of possible cases to check are `2*(3^(n-1))` where `n` is the number of digits of the number on the lhs of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

**The basic idea:** generate all the possible variations of `+`, `-` operators (including the case where the operator is missing), then parse the string and obtain the sum.

**The approach:** combinatorially, it is easy to show that we can do this by associating the operators (or the absence thereof) with the base-3 digits. So we can just iterate over every 8-digit ternary number, but instead of printing 0, 1 and 2, we will append a "+", a "-" or nothing before the next digit in the string.

Note that we do not *actually* need a string for this; one could use digits and operators etc. directly as well, computing the result on the fly. I only took the string-based approach because it's simple to explain, trivial to implement, and additionally, it gives us some visual feedback, which helps understanding the solution.

Now that we have constructed our string, we can just parse it; the simplest solution is to use the C standard library function `strtol()` for this purpose, which will take signs into account and it will return a signed integer. Because of this, we can just sum all the signed integers in a simple loop and we are done.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const char *ops = " +-";

    // 3 ^ 8 = 6561
    for (int i = 0; i < 6561; i++) {
        // first, generate the line
        int k = i;
        std::string line = "1";
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (k % 3)
                line += ops[k % 3];

            k /= 3;
            line += (char)('2' + j);
        }

        // now parse it
        int result = 0;
        const char *s = line.c_str();
        char *p;

        while (*s) {
            int num = strtol(s, &p, 10);
            result += num;
            s = p;
        }

        // output
        std::cout << line << " = " << result << (result == 120 ? " MATCH" : "") << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ ./quirk | grep MATCH
12-3-45+67+89 = 120 MATCH
1+2-34-5+67+89 = 120 MATCH
12-3+4+5+6+7+89 = 120 MATCH
1-23+4+56-7+89 = 120 MATCH
1+2+34-5+6-7+89 = 120 MATCH
123+4+5-6-7-8+9 = 120 MATCH
1+2-3+45+6+78-9 = 120 MATCH
12-3+45+67+8-9 = 120 MATCH
123+4-5+6-7+8-9 = 120 MATCH
123-4+5+6+7-8-9 = 120 MATCH
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$
```

Comment: Interesting, but there are some parts of it that I don't understand, in particular the while loop at the end. Could you explain how that works?

Comment: Also, I don't think this works if you use numbers that are not just 1-9 in order eg 90210=50 or something.

Comment: @user3221115 huh what? why doesn't/wouldn't it work?

Comment: @user3221115 as to the loop: if you read the documentation of `strtol()`, you will perceive that its second argument will be set to point to the first character after the parsed number. So by writing `s = p;`, you go through the textual representation of the numbers (along with the preceding signs), convert them to signed (positive and negative) integers and add those up to obtain the final result.

Answer (score 0):

The following `bool advance(string& s)` function will give you all combinations of `'+'`, `'-'` and `' '` strings of arbitrary length except one and return `false` if no more are available.

```
char advance(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case ' ': return '+';
        case '+': return '-';
        default: case '-': return ' ';
    }
}

bool advance(string& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        if ((s[i] = advance(s[i])) != ' ')
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

You have to first feed it with a string containing only spaces having desired length and then repeat 'advancing' it. Usage:

```
string s = "    ";
while (advance(s))
    cout << '"' << s << '"' << endl;
```

The above code will print

```
"+   "
"-   "
" +  "
"++  "
"-+  "
" -  "
.
.
.
" ---"
"+---"
"----"
```

Note that the 'first' combination with just 4 spaces is not printed.

You can interleave those combinations with your lhs, skipping spaces, to produce expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Another very similar approach, <s>in plain C</s> *OK, in C++ if you really want it that way ;)* and a bit more configurable

The same base 3 number trick is used to enumerate the combinations of void, + and - operators.

The string is handled as a list of positive or negative values that are added together.

The other contribution is very compact and elegant, but uses some C tricks to shorten the code.
This one is hopefully a bit more detailled, albeit not as beautiful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void solver (const char * str, int result)
{
    int op_max = pow(3, strlen(str)); // number of operator permutations

    // loop through all possible operator combinations
    for (int o = 0 ; o != op_max ; o++)
    {
        int res  = 0; // computed operation result
        int sign = 1; // sign of the current value

        int val = str[0]-'0'; // read 1st digit
        string litteral;      // litteral display of the current operation

        // parse remaining digits
        int op;
        for (unsigned i=1, op=o ; i != strlen (str) ; i++, op/=3)
        {
            // get current digit
            int c = str[i]-'0';

            // get current operator
            int oper = op % 3;

            // apply operator
            if (oper == 0) val = 10*val + c;
            else
            {
                // add previous value
                litteral += sign*val;
                res += sign*val;

                // store next sign
                sign = oper == 1 ? 1 : -1;

                // start a new value
                val = c;
            }
        }   

        // add last value
        litteral += sign*val;
        res += sign*val;

        // check result
        if (res == result)
        {
            cout << litteral << " = " << result << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    solver ("123456789", 120);
}
```

Note: I used `std::string`s out of laziness, though they are notoriously slow.

Comment: Plain C is nice and I prefer it wherever possible, but the question was about C++.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah well, technically C is a subpart of C++ :). Anyway, your solution is more elegant than mine.

Comment: **NO NO NO NO.** C is **not** a subset of C++. It never was. There are a **lot** of incompatibilities.

Comment: Just my little joke :). You can easily link C and C++ together, and that's about it.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it doesn't make C a subset of C++. Please don't make wrong assertions, especially when beginners are listening too, because they will get very confused... :-(

Comment: Yes, you're right. Won't do it again, I promise :). Still, this code should compile as C++ too :p

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this could be compiled as C++, as quite a lot of C code.

Comment: @H2C03 Here, you have your C++. Had to correct a signed/unsigned mismatch and change the 'operator' variable name to make it compile, though :)